# How to do bulk update into database using MLCP

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I have to update my database using MLCP means within the database there are multiple collection so a particular collection I have to change the element or attribute, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLCP is intended for loading data into MarkLogic, exporting data from MarkLogic, or copying between MarkLogic instances (with the option to apply transforms during those operations). While you could do an MLCP copy with the input and output hosts and ports the same, with different input_collection and output_collection settings, the right tool for this job is [CORB2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2). In fact, it was built specifically to make in-place changes to content in MarkLogic databases.

Comment: My pleasure. If this answer works for you, could you please mark it "Accepted" so that it will move off the "Unanswered" list?